# Template class methods with different arguments but same code

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I have created a template class that implements various DSP algorithms.  A problem that I have just started running into is that I want to implement the algorithms for both real and complex data, but that means that I have to implement the methods twice even though the bodies of the methods are exactly the same.  An example:

```
template <class T>
class DspAlgorithms {
public:
    DspAlgorithms();
    vector<T> Convolve(vector<T> signal, vector<T> filter);
    vector< complex<T> > Convolve(vector< complex<T> > signal, vector<T> filter);
};
```

I see no way of not declaring and implementing the methods twice even though they have the exact same code inside.  Is there a clever way to avoid just copying and pasting the entire method implementation?

Comment: Are you sure you need to implement that method twice? What is wrong with the first  implementation?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the first implementation, but I don't think it can cover the 2nd situation which is "signal" is complex vector of T while "filter" is vector of T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you have a template already, why not turn the functions into function templates as well?

```
template <class T>
class DspAlgorithms {
public:
    DspAlgorithms();
    template <class U>
    vector<U> Convolve(vector<U> signal, vector<T> filter);
};
```

If you want to limit the function to be callable with `T` and `complex<T>` only, you can use `enable_if` (C++11 or Boost):

```
template <class U>
vector<U> Convolve(vector<U> signal, vector<T> filter, typename enable_if<is_same<U, T>::value || is_same<U, complex<T> >::value>::type * = 0);
```

Comment: Another option that doesn't require C++11 or boost is to make `template <class U> vector<U> Convolve(vector<U> signal, vector<T> filter);` private, and then call that template from (non-templated) public overloaded functions.